# @Autowired is not working with beans defined in application context file

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I defined a bean in spring context file 'applicationContext.xml' like below :

```
<bean id="daoBean" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.xxx.DAOImpl" />
</bean>
```

In my service class (ServiceImpl), I am using this bean like below:

```
 @Component("serviceImpl")
 public class ServiceImpl{
        // other code here

        @Autowired
        private transient DAOImpl daoBean;

        // other code here
    }
```

My service class is being accessed from my JUnit test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" }) 
public class JUnitTest{
    // other code here

    @Autowired
    private transient ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    // test cases are here
}
```

When I execute the test case, it gives error saying:

> Error creating bean with name 'ServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private transient com.xxx.DAOImpl

When I remove  @Autowired from service class and use @Resource(name = "daoBean") the test case works fine.

```
public class ServiceImpl{
            // other code here

            @Resource(name = "daoBean")
            private transient DAOImpl daoBean;

            // other code here
        }
```

My question is why @Autowired is not working in this case? Do I need to configure any thing else with @Autowired, so that it can work properly. I don't want to change my service layer classes to replace @Autowired to @Resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Mockito.mock()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.java#Mockito.mock%28java.lang.Class%29) has a generic return type `T` which is erased at runtime, so Spring cannot infer the type of the created mock that will be simply registered as `Object` in the Spring context. That's why `@Autowired` doesn't work (as it tries to look up the dependency by its type).

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158409/1276804) for a solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer. Now I got it.